# Relation problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, relations

Let $A = \{1,2,3,4\}$ and let $f: \mathcal{P}(A)\to\mathbb{N}$ be the function defined by saying that $f(X)$ is the sum of elements of $X$, for each $X\in \mathcal{P}(A)$. (If $X = \emptyset$, then by convention we say that $f(X)=0$). Define the relation $\sim$ on $\mathcal{P}(A)$ as follows:

$X\sim Y$ if and only if $f(X) > f(Y)$ or $X = Y$.

Write down whether $\sim$ is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, transitive.

---

The part where I am struggling is to prove reflexivity.

Reflexive: $a\sim a$ for all $a$. So that means $f(X) > f(Y)$ is false, since $f(X) > f(X)$ is false.

But $X = Y$ part is true since, $X = X$ for all $X \in\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: I got an extra follow up question to this. 

If I were to prove for Symmetry:

there will be four cases.
1) if $f(X) > f(Y)$ then $f(Y) > f(X)$ (False)
2) if $X = Y$ then $Y = X$ (True)
3) if $f(X) > f(Y)$ then $Y = X$ (False)
4) if $X = Y$ then $f(Y) > f(X)$ (False)

In that case, is this relation a symmetric relation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you think about it correctly, but inefficient, what makes it confusing to you.

As you said, to prove reflexivity you have to show that $x\sim x$ for every $x$.

Now the set $X$ is in relation with itself, since $X=X$ always holds, and then you are already done. So there is no need to mention that $f(X)>f(X)$ does not hold (which is a correct observation).

Comment: Ahh ok, so that means that S is reflexive then?

Comment: Yes, your relation is reflexive.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: You are welcome. :)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have a relation $W$ (for “whatever”) on a set $C$ and define, for $a,b\in C$,

> $a\mathrel{R}b$ if and only if $a\mathrel{W}b$ or $a=b$

then the relation $R$ is necessarily reflexive: the predicate

> $a\mathrel{W}a$ or $a=a$

is true for every $a\in C$; the truth value of $a\mathrel{W}a$ is completely irrelevant and should not even be mentioned in the proof.

Try and think in more abstract terms so the details of the exercise don't distract you from the main task.

In your case $C=\mathcal{P}(A)$ and the relation $W$ is defined by $X\mathrel{W}Y$ for $f(X)>f(Y)$.

*Side note* 1. A similar problem will show up with the proof of transitivity: be very careful.

*Side note* 2. An edit to the question masked off another mistake you made. The relation you had was called $S$, but in the attempted proof you called it $R$. This might just be a typo, but not using the correct symbol might earn you a lower grade.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the explanation. So for transitivity, S is a transitive too right?
Because *f(X)*>*f(X)*, and *f(Y)* > *f(Z)*, then *f(X)* > *f(Z)*

Comment: @BryanHii You're not being careful! ;-) Retry: there are *four* cases to analyze. By the way, type `$f(X)>f(y)$` rather than `*f(X)*>*f(Y)*`

Comment: I thought of something but I do not know if it is correct. Because transitivity means that when aRb and bRc, then aRc. So in my case, if X = Y, and $f(Y)$ > $f(Z)$, then X = Z is False, because X cannot be equal to Z. Am I thinking in the right direction?

Comment: @BryanHii No, I'm afraid.